# What causes network data use besides automatic updates?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, network

Yesterday I updated my old OS to Yosemite. I saw that automatic updates were using a lot of data so I turned them off them off in System Preferences. After restarting my computer, I checked **Activity Monitor > Network**, and Received Data shows 1.67GB

What uses data besides automatic updates? Is there a way to reduce the data usage?

Comment: Do you use iCloud? Dropbox? Google Drive? iCloud Photos? iTunes?

Comment: No Sir. yet I do not enter **Apple ID** or download any app or software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right guys, I found the solution. I went to **Finder > Library > Updates** then I saw the bunch of update files their. So, I had deleted all those files and connect to Internet. Well, now it is OK. :D